# Azure node.js functions to update/retrieve an entity in azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

How to update Azure node.js functions to update/retrieve an entity in azure table storage . Only method I found in functions is for inserting an entry.
So how can the table be queried/updated?

The task is to simpy retrieve data on the basis of rowkey and partition key and then increment the value of key value pair stored as `{"num":val}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read through "Storage table input binding" at [Azure Functions Storage table bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table). It has examples of `function.json` and Node function.

If something is still not clear, please refine your question with the exact problem.

UPDATE:

Here is a sample solution for your refined problem. I only have it in C#, I hope you can derive node implementation.

`csx`

```cs
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public class Entity : TableEntity
{
    public int num {get; set;}
}

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string partition, 
    string rowkey, Entity inputEntity, out Entity outputEntity)
{
    if (inputEntity == null)
        outputEntity = new Entity { PartitionKey = partition, RowKey = rowkey, num = 1};
    else
    {
        inputEntity.num += 1;
        outputEntity = inputEntity;
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"Done, num = {outputEntity.num}");
}
```

`function.json`:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "HttpTriggerTableUpdate/{partition}/{rowkey}"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "inputEntity",
      "tableName": "MyTable",
      "partitionKey": "{partition}",
      "rowKey": "{rowkey}",
      "connection": "my_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outputEntity",
      "tableName": "MyTable",
      "partitionKey": "{partition}",
      "rowKey": "{rowkey}",
      "connection": "my_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: The link doesn't provide with method to query/update/delete an entity in azure-tables using node.js azure functions bindings. Can you provide a code snippet for that. Also the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492777/how-to-update-a-azure-table-row-in-azure-function-using-bindings  addresses the same issue. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: The standard azure-table method of replaceEntity etc show error

Comment: @sameeksha If you need arbitrary queries/deletes etc, you would have to do that manually without direct help from Function bindings. I can't give you a snippet for a task which is not specified by you.

Comment: manually as in? The task is to simpy retrieve data on the basis of rowkey and partition key and then increment the value of key value pair stored as {"num":val}. Can you provide link to some source where I can read from. Pretty new to azure and msdn blogs and documentation is hard to catch up with.

Comment: @sameeksha Added a sample to increment a key in a row. Next time please specify your use case as full as possible, without being asked several times.