# How to edit azure storage table from azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am able to add new row in table using code below

```
context.bindings.sampleTable = {
"partitionKey": "11111111",
"rowKey": "222",
"deviceId": 1111,
"messageId": 2222,
"temperature": 3333,
"humidity": 4444
 };

 context.done();
```

now I want to edit this new added row so I tried same code with same `partitionkey` and `rowkey` but it gives error as below

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.CCCJSFunc. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter _binder after function returned:. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The specified entity already exists.
```

so please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The thread [How to update a Azure table row in Azure function using Bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492777/how-to-update-a-azure-table-row-in-azure-function-using-bindings) addresses the same issue. Currently, if you need arbitrary updates/deletes etc, you would have to do that manually with [Azure Storage SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node).

You can check out this blog post: [Updating and Deleting Table Storage Entities with Azure Functions (C# and JavaScript)](http://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-update-delete-table-storage/) for a workaround.